# Role based authorization in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

**Hi am new ASP.NET MVC. Currently am learning MVCmusicstore tutorial from asp.net official website.But Iam getting error while executing the project after implementing  role based authorization in it.The stack trace is given below.Please advice**

Stack Trace:

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.DurableInstancing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.

The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0

System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98

System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241

System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69

System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1136

System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111

System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +23

System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +60

System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.CreateModules() +221

System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +28

System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +828

System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +304

System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107

System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a reference to the following assembly:

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
```

Right-click on the project, select "Add Reference" and add this assembly.